# Redis keys are presented as strings, not objects

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to get data from Redis session with nodejs - but i can't get the inner values of the objects....

this is a simple router

```
      router.get('/page-user', function (req, res) {

      console.log(redis_model.prototype.getAll());


      })
```

and here is the model

```
  redis_model.prototype.getAll = function () {

    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
       }
     });
   };
```

So i'm getting

```
 users
 id:users
 session:php:cf5myWFkDNEPwiRLpi6M1P6LqX1UPFtj //object
 user:{58}
```

I'm trying to fetch data from the session key and i'm getting Undefined , like this:

```
redis_model.prototype.getAll = function () {

 client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(keys['session']);  // tried also keys.session

});
};
```

The part that i can't figure out is why i get Type String for all the keys - like here:

```
redis_model.prototype.getAll = function () {

    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);


        console.log(typeof keys[i]); result : //string,string, string,string

   });
};
```

I've tried HGETALL to get the keys as objects but i still get undefined :

```
  redis_model.prototype.getAll = function () {

    client.hgetall("session",function(data){console.log(data)});
  };
```

Here is a screenshot of the redis db...

[image]

Comment: Redis keys are _always_ strings.

Answer (score 0):

`Client.keys("*",function(err,keys){})`

This just returns all the keys present in the redisDB which are basically strings

Instead you can use

> client.get('key',function(err,data){})

inorder to get the result as an object it should be stored as a hash i.e

```
client.hmset("session",{'php':'cf5myWFkDNEPwiRLpi6M1P6LqX1UPFtj'}
client.hgetall("session",function(data){console.log(data.php)})
```

the above code gives you the value assigned to php.

Comment: nuy5 - thanks - i've updated the question - i've tried using HGETALL but still gets undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Got it....

```
redis_model.prototype.getAll = function () {

client.get('session:php:VfAPTh_NLpBrcq3VGHTC8uT7c-sF4bQd', function(err, 
 result){
    var foo = (JSON.parse(result))['user'];
    console.log( foo);
  });
};
```